# Where can I ask questions regarding Firefox?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I can't seem to find info on installing a Swedish language package on my machine. The language is not listed [on their website](https://addons.mozilla.org/sv-se/firefox/language-tools/) and the hits on Google I got led nowhere (or, rather, to the said page).

Where can I ask such a question (within the realm of Stack Exchange)?

Comment: Super User seems to be the place for this question. If it's well written.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Would you say that the formulation above constitutes a well written question? Also, the remark I made as a comment to the other reply - isn't it a bit too simple question to be posted there?

Comment: Use good grammar, punctuation, and show what you've tried. They can't expect much more than that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sounds like it  would be appropriate on [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: Hmmm... I'm not arguing you but isn't that a question a bit too basic to be posted on **Super** User? I'd rather not get -10000 reputation because of such a thing.   :)

Comment: **If** it's too basic, don't ask it. But then I can think of no other site where it would be appropriate. Barring a relevant chat room on SU, you're on your own.

Comment: There's much, much worse there, believe me. A question about installing a language in a major web browser is very much on topic for [su]. In fact, that's really the only place in the network for such a question.

Comment: @Chamster: Please keep in mind that other people might share your problem. They might be very happy to find a proper answer on Super User (after you've posted your question). And, yes, your question will be welcome on [su] :)

Comment: @Bart My point was that I can't tell if it's too basic. I don't want to cause a storm of rage like the last time when a few contributors misunderstood my point. That's why I'm asking first.

Comment: @AlEverett & OliverSalzburg Got it. Thank you for a straightforward reply. Will check the answer green as soon as SO'll let me!

Comment: @Chamster Sure. No problem. That's why I said "if". And perhaps probing in an on-topic chat room might not be a bad idea anyway. I can't judge the question though. I'm not active on the site.

Comment: @Bart Chat room? What do you mean? MSN?

Comment: Every Stack Exchange site has an associated [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) room. Check the links at the top of the page.

Comment: No, each site has their own chat rooms. If you have sufficient rep (20 I think) you can participate. The link named "chat" at the very top of the page leads to the chat rooms for that particular SO/SE

Comment: Sight... I thought Meta was a common forum for all the sections... And chat, I don't think I've seen it... Might be a bit hard to find the right chat room for every uncertainty one has. But still - a good tip.