# What is the right site for asking a question about how to configure a browser, such as Firefox, Firefox ESR?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

What is the right site for asking a question about how to configure a browser such as like Firefox, [Firefox ESR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefox#Experimental_builds_and_ESR)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where can I ask questions regarding Firefox?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148582/where-can-i-ask-questions-regarding-firefox)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Super User](https://superuser.com) would seem like the right place. It has a [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) tag as well as tags for other browsers and has various well received configuration questions such as [Firefox: Remember new passwords without prompting](https://superuser.com/questions/73444/firefox-remember-new-passwords-without-prompting).

Check the [help centre](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) and other Firefox questions to make sure yours fits. Maybe yours already exists with an answer.