# Does Meta SE automatically remove signatures?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, quality-filter, automatic-edits, signatures

This is derived from finding [What is the right site for asking a question about how to configure a browser, such as Firefox, Firefox ESR?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/386604/289691). The original revision, included `THX`. This word looks that means "thanks", also as initials, but it doesn't match the username, in either case qualify as a "signature"). I understand that there are changes done automatically but I don't know to what extend it includes signatures or only specific words.

NOTE: This is not a feature request and this post will not be converted into one.

I'm wondering several things:

1. If the "automatic removal of signatures / greetings" (let’s call it "tool") is in place in Meta SE *as `THX` was manually removed (see [revision 2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/386604/2))*.
2. If a current *tool* has a rule that should catch posts remove words like `THX` (new line, having very few characters, i.e. like initials, acronyms or like in the case of the referred question, unusual abbreviations of "thank you").
3. ... (other things like the post should not be pass the quality filter, that will not include in this post as it will make this question to "need more focus" )

---

[ask-wizard](/questions/tagged/ask-wizard) is for questions about the Ask Question Wizard. At this time it's only available in Stack Overflow. Questions posted using it shows a label in the post timeline. This question is about the implementation of the Ask Question Form / Page in Meta SE.

Related

- [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/289691)
- [Let's make the automatic removal of salutations language specific!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/305125/289691)
- [The question wizard might be useful for Meta Stack Exchange too; should we give it a try?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/327257/289691)
- [The new ask page is now live on the network!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344513/289691)

Comment: Pretty rude to call Shadow Wizard a "tool": https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/386604/2

Comment: @rene Thanks for you feedback (I should say that in comments like the above it would be nice to have some sort of tone indicator / emoji). I thought that the "automatic removal of signatures / greetings" was an obvious feature of the ask-wizard that work before the question were posted.

Comment: @Rubén Why do you think the question was created through the wizard? If it were, it would be stated in the time line, like in this question https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75419036/timeline

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz You are right, sorry. I want to say ask question form. I was confused as I meta didn't had a tag for the question form as SO has.

Comment: @Rubén Ah, then your comment makes more sense. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only [salutations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93989/295232) are removed by the system, not signatures. The Meta Stack Exchange community is sometimes a system of its own, and you can definitely count on signatures like that being removed here, given the amount of regulars vs. the amount of new posts. But it's all human work.

I'm not sure if Meta Stack Exchange (or any other site) would benefit from automatic removal of signatures. It's not like they're causing *real* harm, and false positives would be quite embarrassing, requiring extra effort to circumvent.

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering if there was a glitch or something needs an adjustment.

Comment: By the way, do you know if "`The **thanks parts at the end of posts** are much more difficult / risky to detect, so we are not touching those for now.`" (emphasis mine) is still *as is* currently?

Comment: I don't know, but I guess "Thanks" is much more often used as the first word of a long sentence, making it harder to delete automatically without breaking the grammar. Yes, often entire final lines starting with "Thanks" can be removed, but again you want to avoid false positives as much as possible.